# Como fazer pra inverter os digitos de um vetor e imprimi-los separadamente ? E tem como diferenciar 000 de 0 em C?

Tags: c

Tenho que fazer um programa de inverter os dígitos de um numero e imprimi-lo entre colchetes [];
Pra começar , o loop de leitura tem que para quando o numero digitado for igual a 0, porem se o valor for uma sequencia de 0s ele tem que continuar(ex:000 ou 00);
E não sei se minha lógica está certa , podem me ajudar?
segue o código da leitura:

```
    do
{
    scanf("%d", &n[i]);
    k=n[i];
    i++;
}while(k!=0);
```

e o código inteiro:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  int main ()
  {
    int n[100],v[100],a[100],b[100];
    int i=0,cont,j,k,x,y,t,p;
    do
    {
      scanf("%d", &n[i]);
      k=n[i];
      i++;
    }while(k!=0);
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
{
    if(n[j]>=1000)
    {
        p=n[j]/1000;
        v[j]=n[j]%1000;

        if(v[j]>=100)
        {
            y=v[j]/100;
            a[j]=v[j]%100;
            if(a[j]>=10)
            {
                t=a[j]/10;
                b[j]=a[j]%10;
                printf("[%d][%d][%d][%d]\n", a[j]%10,t,y,p);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(n[j]>=100 && n[j]<1000)
    {
        y=n[j]/100;
        a[j]=n[j]%100;
        if(a[j]>=10)
        {
            t=a[j]/10;
            b[j]=a[j]%10;
            printf("[%d][%d][%d]\n", a[j]%10,t,y);
        }
    }

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Matematicamente zeros à esquerda são totalmente dispensáveis, não existe nenhuma diferença entre o número 0 e 000. Talvez você não queira considerar como número mas sim como uma cadeia de caracteres e, aí sim "'0" é diferente de "000".

Comment: `000` não é um numero, e por isso o problema começa logo ai. Leia tudo como texto e nem sequer terá problema

Comment: como char?Porque no enunciado do problema diz que se o numero digitado for 000 , ele deve imprimir só 0, mas se for digitado 000 o resto nem executa

Comment: leia com char,isso deverá resolver o problema

Answer (score 0):

A lógica do programa que está na pergunta é muito confusa, nem tentei entender.
Abaixo vai um programa com uma lógica que acredito seja muito mais simples.

PS. Os professores nunca falam em documentação, comentários ? No programa que está na pergunta não existe nem um mísero comentário!

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, n_digits, valid_number;

  // vai tratar numeros com no maximo 4 digitos
  char digits[5];

  for (;;)
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* digite um numero: ");

    // le uma string com no maximo 4 caracteres, ignora restante da linha
    scanf("%4s%*[^\n]", digits);

    // verifica se foi digitado um numero valido
    valid_number = 1;
    n_digits = strlen(digits);
    for (i = 0; i < n_digits; i++)
      if (!isdigit(digits[i]))
      {
        valid_number = 0;
        break;
      }

    if (!valid_number)
    {
      printf("* nao foi digitado um numero valido, tente novamente\n");
      continue;
    }

    // se foi digitado apenas um zero e nada mais, termina loop
    if (n_digits == 1 && digits[0] == '0')
      break;

    // mostra o numero na ordem inversa
    printf("* [");

    for (i = n_digits; i > 0; i--)
      printf("%c", digits[i-1]);

    printf("]\n");
  }

  printf("*\n");
}
```